# Vue.js 2 Route Not Working. Posts Variable not Accessible

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

First project in `Vue.js`. Working with `WP REST API`.

I am able to get all my posts to show, but as soon as I try to implement the `Vue-router` my component that shows all the posts, `home-post-list`, dies at the first `v-if="posts"` statement.

Clearly, `Vue` thinks there is no posts so it isn't rendering anything else, but I cannot figure out how to make it recognize `posts`. I don't get any errors in the console.

WhenI look at the `Vue DevTools`, I see:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5441k1kw8ocmzad/Screenshot%202018-05-22%2010.43.24.png?dl=0

So, the `router-view` appears to be working properly, but props is empty. I thought I was passing props from the main instance to the child component but maybe I am doing something wrong here.

I will show you my current code.

***HomePostList component

```
const HomePostList = Vue.component('home-post-list', {
  props:['posts'],
  template: `<div class="cell medium-8">
                        <div id="all-posts" class="all-posts" v-if="posts">
                        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                          <div class="post medium-6 cell" :class="{'medium-12':index===0}" v-for="(post,index) in posts">
                            <div class="img-bg" :class="{'first-post':index === 0}" :style="'background-image: url(' + post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url + ')'"></div>
                            <aside class="post-meta grid-x">
                              <div class="cell small-12">
                                <h3>{{ post.title.rendered | limitWords(6) }}</h3>

                              </div>
                              <div class="cell small-6">
                                <div class="post-category" v-for="(category,index) in post.cat_name.slice(0,1)">
                                  <a :href="'/category/' + category.slug">{{ category.cat_name }}</a>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="cell small-6">
                                                <p><i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i> &nbsp;{{ post.date | parseTime }}</p>
                              </div>
                            </aside>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>`
});
```

***SinglePost Component

```
const SinglePost = Vue.component('single-post-template', {
  props:['posts'],
  template: `<div class="cell medium-8">
                    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
                        <p>Single Post here</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>`
});
```

***Routes & Vue Instance

```
const routes = [
  {
        path: '/',
        component: HomePostList,
        props: true
  },
  { 
        path: '/post/:postId',
        name: 'post',
        component: SinglePost
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data() {
    return{
      posts: [],
      searchTerm:'',
      searchPosts:[],
      currentRoute: window.location.pathname
    }
  },
  created (){
    var $this = this;
    axios
      .get(apiRoot + 'posts?_embed')
      .then(function (response) {
        $this.posts = response.data;
      }
    )
  },
  methods: {
    loadMorePosts: function(){
        var $this = this;
        axios
          .get(apiRoot + 'posts?_embed')
          .then(function (response) {
            $this.posts = response.data;
          }
        )
    },
  },
  computed:{

  },

});
```

***index.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Front
*/
get_header(); ?>

<!-- Home Page -->
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

    <!-- Main Post Container -->
    <router-view></router-view>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar" class="cell medium-4">
      <sidebar-search></sidebar-search>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: can you make any live demo ?

Comment: values in `data` are only available to the component where it's defined. The data in root component won't be accessible in child components. If you want a centralized place to store your post data for all component to use, check out Vuex.

Comment: So, if I move my data values to their respective components, they should be accessible, I take it. I thought that was what `props` was for but I must be mistaken

Comment: @NateBeers pardon me if I'm being rude, If you want to learn the VueJs they have the amazing [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) and [playground](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/50wL7mdz/) I suggest you start with. [Here's](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) the working simple sample you can use to extend already working application. A the end of the day you can just open html file in browser instead of serving it from PHP server. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by adding posts to the `router-view` element.

```
<router-view :posts="posts"></router-view>
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but it works.